# Caching all queries

Tags: php, mysql

im a php hobbyist and i working on a new article system. Ive made a class that takes care of simple database actions. This class retrieves table names and auto increment fields every time the class its launched, to create an object that matches the database table. So while i was working on my article system i checked out the query log that my database class generates, and i noticed 35 queries on a simple page.

Now i made a small cache class :

```
<?php

namespace library;

class cache {

    private static $instance;

    public $arDBFields = array ();

    public $arAIFields = array ();

    public $arQueryResults = array ();

    public static function get() {
        if(! self::$instance){
            self::$instance = new self ();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function setDBFields($name, $value) {
        $this->arDBFields [$name] [] = $value;
    }

    public function getDBFields($name) {
        if(! empty ( $this->arDBFields [$name] ))
            return $this->arDBFields [$name];

        return array ();
    }

    public function setAIField($name, $value) {
        $this->arAIFields [$name] = $value;
    }

    public function getAIField($name) {
        if(! empty ( $this->arAIFields [$name] ))
            return $this->arAIFields [$name];

        return array ();
    }

    public function setQueryResult($name, $cacheshit) {
        $this->arQueryResults [$name] = $cacheshit;
    }

    public function getQueryResult($name) {

        if(! empty ( $this->arQueryResults [$name] ))
            return $this->arQueryResults [$name];

        return array ();
    }

}
```

?>

and in my mysql class i added this :

```
if(!empty($cachedValue)){
            $this->query = $cachedValue ;
        }
        else {
            $this->query = mysql_query ($sql , $this->connection);
            cache::get()->setQueryResult($sql, $this->query);
        }
```

It also skips writing to the query log array if it has a not empty $cachedvalue

Now my query log shows 6 queries for this page, and that's the bare minimum in has to use for the page.

My question kinda is, is this good to do or are there better ways to reduce queries ?

Comment: does it need any ? Can all of the queries be cached as HTML templates and then when data changes remove the html cache ?

Comment: I guess your logic is flawed when you can reduce 35 hits to 6 with a simple cache that will survive only one run. It shows your querying the same data quite a lot. On the other hand [MySQL has it's own query cache already](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html)

Answer (score 0):

Caching is a good thing to do, particularly if your content does not change frequently.  Many PHP frameworks will do this for you, in fact.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a Windows/IIS environment then you can install WinCache and take advantage of the User Cache option to store frequently accessed data in memory, so the benefit is there for multiple page requests (depending on how long you set the TTL). Installing WinCache is very easy and also makes your code run faster as it's basic function is to cache OPCode so PHP doesn't have to create OPCode every request.

WinCache is what I have experience with, but I'm sure that most web server applications (Apache, IIS, etc.) have something similar (APC is popular on Apache).

http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/wincache-extension

To directly answer your question. Writing your own caching code will help build better understanding of PHP in general, which I think is a good thing. However, to get the most bang for your buck you should probably integrate an existing caching mechanism and write code around it.